# how to store different types of data in flutter secure storage

Tags: security, types, boolean, storage

I am new to flutter and I am using flutter secure storage to store user credentials. so I searched on the internet that how can I store different types of data into flutter secure storage as it is allowing me to store only string types of data. I want to store boolean values like login into it, but I did not find any proper answer. Please, someone, confirm me, can I store or not different types of data also into it, instead of String data.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use some sort of type parsing.
For bool:

1. To write to Secure Storage:

   ```
   await _secureStorage.write(key: _key, value: boolValue.toString());
   ```
2. To read from Secure Storage:

   ```
   var value = await _secureStorage.red(key: _key);
   ```

Value will be of type String, you can then "cast" it to bool:

```
bool boolValue = value.toLowerCase() == 'true';
```

.toLowerCase() just in case, somehow in Secure Storage will be True.

For int you can do:

```
int i = int.parse('42');
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about the [`flutter_secure_storage` package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage): it supports strings only.

If you want to store other types of data, you can encode them as a string. The most convenient way to do that is probably [JSON](https://dart.dev/guides/json). You can use `jsonEncode` and `jsonDecode` from the [`dart:convert`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) library.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you please give an example code to do that.